# RegExp (javascript) :: find a group of php variables including the $ character (Enlighter JS)

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm trying to find several custom php variables out of a whole "code block" string to enlighten them via EnlighterJS (v3.3) 
https://github.com/EnlighterJS/EnlighterJS/commit/a5854c3455b68790aa21d56e2ceb7b734dd72913

In my php code block I'm using a bunch of repeating custom variables which could be considered most likely as global constants like:

`$TIME_MS, $GET_URL, $FILE_TYPE`

I managed to enlighten the constants **without the $ character:**

`regex: /\b(TIME_MS|GET_URL|FILE_TYPE)\b`

**But how can I catch the $ character as well?**
**This didn't work:**

`/\b(\$TIME_MS|\$GET_URL|\$FILE_TYPE)\b`

Thanks and best,

Maxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to work now:

```
    { 
      regex: /(\$TIME_MS|\$GET_URL|\$FILE_TYPE)\b/gi,
      type: "gvar",
    },
```

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fXkI5O/3)

Correct me if I missed something like line breaks and stuff

Answer (score 0):

Word boundaries won't work in front of a `$` character, because this is not a word character.  `\b` finds boundaries between word and non-word characters.  Instead, you may use `(?<!\S)\$`:

```
(?<!\S)\$(TIME_MS|GET_URL|FILE_TYPE)\b
```

### Demo

If your regex tool does not support lookbehinds, then perhaps you can just search for a space character before the `$`.  Though, this would not catch cases where a `$` variable happens to begin the line or input.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this gives me an error. Am I missing something?

My full line:

`regex: /(?<!\S)\$(TIME_MS|GET_URL|FILE_TYPE)\b/,`

Comment: @Maxxx Yes, that's right, check the demo where the pattern is working.  As I mentioned in the second half of my answer, maybe your regex tool does not support lookbehinds.  In this case, just put a space before the `$`: `[ ]\$(HIDE_WHOLE_CONTROL|HIDE_PART_NOTHING)\b`

Comment: I know why it gave me an error now because the regex is inside bracelets. So I had to escape the parentheses. But now it still doesn't catch the $ probably because of the escaping?!
`{
regex: /\(?<!\S\)\$(TIME_MS|GET_URL|FILE_TYPE)\b/gi,
type:"gvar"
},`

Comment: The regex you posted in the comment above is invalid and won't work anywhere.

Comment: Yes true, my former regex still catches the strings after the $.
But is there any workaround without the `(?<!\S)`? Because this definitely gives me critical errors together with EnlighterJS :(

Comment: I have already given you a workaround ... did you really read my answer?

Comment: Yeah sorry, you mean the space before the $?
I've tried that one and tested it already. It doesn't give me any errors but it also doesn't catch the $. No matter what I'm trying. I'm not really experienced with regex but it seems like I'm fighting several battles. @regex101.com everything works but not with EnlighterJS for some reason?! I even changed the position and put your regex on top because I thought maybe my former regex coming before the new ones are kind of "dominate". But that didn't help either. I'm really out of ideas right now.